# Switching GridbagLayout on the fly

Tags: java, swing, runtime, gridbaglayout

Hey guys.How do I switch or change all the JButton of GridBagLayout when I press a button? It seems stuck. It won't replace the old one.....Please help me... I tried repaint(), revalidate() but "sigh" it just won't work. Please correct me.

```
package gridlayoutjumper;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GridLayoutJumper extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JFrame timeTableFrame = new JFrame("Helo");  
    JPanel timeTablePnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Jbutton1");
    JButton jb4 = new JButton("Change");
    JButton jb3 = new JButton("Jbutton3");
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Jbutton2");

    public GridLayoutJumper(){

    }

    public void newLayout1(){

        System.out.println("newLayout1 executed");
        JButton jb5 = new JButton("Jbutton5");
        JButton jb6 = new JButton("Jbutton6");
        JButton jb7 = new JButton("Jbutton7");

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15); 
        timeTablePnl.add(jb5, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15);  
        timeTablePnl.add(jb6, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15);  
        timeTablePnl.add(jb7, c);

        timeTablePnl.validate();
        timeTablePnl.repaint();
    }

    public void createComponent(){
        timeTableFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        timeTableFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        timeTableFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        timeTableFrame.add(timeTablePnl);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15);
        timeTablePnl.add(jb1, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15); 
        timeTablePnl.add(jb2, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15);  
        timeTablePnl.add(jb3, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15);  
        timeTablePnl.add(jb4, c);

        jb4.addActionListener(this); 
        timeTableFrame.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == jb4){
            System.out.println("Gotcha");
            newLayout1();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridLayoutJumper x = new GridLayoutJumper();
        x.createComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the old components from their container first:

```
public void newLayout1() {

    timeTablePnl.remove(jb1);
    timeTablePnl.remove(jb2);
    timeTablePnl.remove(jb3);

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I think GridBagLayout simply ignores components inserted at the same grid coordinate otherwise.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? What if I created jLabel instead of jButton dynamically. Means, I loop to create the jLabel and insert it into gridbaglayout without specifically naming each jLabel. All the jLabel is having the same name in different place of gridbaglayout.

By the way, I need this to make a time table. Please assist, ty!